# How to get the row of the matched statement?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am grabbing a feed from API and and here I want to get the row that starts with ,,[[,2 . Please help me how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RegExp that I came up with in PHP is:

```
$s = ',,[[,2thesecretoflife';
$r = preg_match('/^,,\\[\\[,2/', $s);

if ($r) {
  echo 'works';
}
```

Basically, you have to double escape the `[`s to get them to be interpreted properly. I'm sure that whatever language you are using would be similar.

Comment: Thanks vansimke .  But using preg_match it gave me this . Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in

Comment: Please i need this urgent ..help me

Comment: Try this version. preg_match apparently needs to surround the pattern with `/`. Link to PHP doc: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php